# VBA CubeField filter

Tags: excel, vba, pivot-table

For a normal pivot table I'm doing

```
For Each item In .PivotTables("table1").PivotFields("field1").PivotItems
    If item.Value = "asdf" Then
        item.Visible = True
    Else
        item.Visible = False
    End If
Next item
```

where `field1` is not a page field. Can I do the same in a data model pivot table? I've read about CubeFields but I don't have PowerPivot installed.

Answer (score 1):

No documentation or forum or videotutorial could drive me to this answer, so I share it for the sake of future humanity.

```
.PivotTables("table1").CubeFields( _
    "[MyDB].[field1]").CreatePivotFields
.PivotTables("table1").PivotFields( _
    "[MyDB].[field1].[field1]").VisibleItemsList = Array( _
    "[MyDB].[field1].&[asdf])
```

Replace `MyDB`, `table1`, `field1` and `asdf` with your own objects.